# group by and sum values based on different rows

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, data-science, data-analysis

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
store      itemId       numberOfItemsSold
Berlin     1            78
Amsterdam  3            12
Berlin     2            31
Amsterdam  1            12
Berlin     1            90
```

I want to create a dataset or dictionary such that I have accumulated information regarding how many of EACH item was sold in each different store. For example, in Berlin, 78+90 items were sold of itemId = 1. Then, 31 items were sold where itemId = 2.

How can I extract such information for each store for each different product (itemId)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), this would give a DataFrame:

```
summary_df = df.groupby(['store', 'itemId']).sum()
```

If you want a dictionary:

```
summary_dict = dict(zip(summary_df.index, summary_df.numberOfItemsSold))
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the `pd.DataSet.groupby()` work for you?

```py
pd.DataFrame(
[["Berlin", 1, 78],
["Amsterdam",3, 12],
["Berlin",2, 31],
["Amsterdam", 1,12],
["Berlin", 1, 90]], 
columns=["store", "itemId", "numberOfItemsSold"]).groupby(['store', 'itemId']).sum().reset_index()
```

output:

```
store   itemId  numberOfItemsSold
0   Amsterdam   1   12
1   Amsterdam   3   12
2   Berlin  1   168
3   Berlin  2   31
```

Comment: This would give me ```AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'groupby'``` Also, I think there's an extra bracket